# Is HIIT healthy practiced long term?

Tags: cardio, hiit

I have done steady rate cardio for the bulk of my cardio exercises. I recently found out about HIIT and it's after burner effect and am interested to give it a try.

I am still apprehensive about trying it out because of the high heart rate doing it would involve. The reason why I am apprehensive is because of people like Dr. Maffetone and his [Maffetone method](http://philmaffetone.com/what-is-the-maffetone-method/) which cautions of having too high heart rates during exercise. Maffetone method in a nutshell advocates very low heart rates when doing cardio.

Is HIIT really safe for the long term ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe for the long term and no problem for you heart or joints, see [Why your workout should be high-intensity](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/01/26/sweaty-answer-to-chronic-illness/?_r=0).

Regarding injuries in general, see the [study of 300 patients with rheumatoid arthritis](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/art.11216/pdf). This group is more sensitive than healthy people to damage of the large joints. After two years of study, there was no damage.

On a personal level, I have been doing high intensity workouts about once a week since the age of 11. My experience is that injuries of joints and/or heart failures occur when you do it in a "no pain - no gain" context, i.e. team sports or races.

However, before starting a high intensity program, do a health check up and start with small, short doses.

Comment: Once a week is not the same as using HIIT as your main basis of training. The jury is still out as far as long term (15+ years), as it has not been around as a concept and fad for that long.